# How can I use choice_fields in my models.py file and how to represent them in my output?

Tags: django-rest-framework, modelchoicefield

I'm trying to include an attribute in models named as 'action' to show the action status of particular todo items. And for that I've tried to create these files but its not working as per my requirements.

I expected a dropdown or checkboxes but didn't get them yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your post to provide more details, including your code, to help us answer this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create using charfields

```
class Model:
  choices = (
    (a, a),
     (b,b)
  )
 choice = models.charField(choices=choices )
```

Comment: class Model(models.Model):

Comment: also max_length and default should be included.